# how to start a Tomcat webapp from a Windows .bat

Tags: java, file, batch-file, tomcat, web-applications

I am trying to run Tomcat webapps  from  bat files, some of them with the Windows scheduler and some when an application and network monitor detects that its process is down

Can anybody tell me where is this subject explained. Thanks in advance!

Comment: By _"running a webapp"_ you mean starting Tomcat or opening a page of the application?

Comment: The latter, to have the webapp up and running

Comment: To be clearer, I need to know what methods or services Tomcat has to start or stop the webapp in an automated way from Windows. That is, functions similar to those that are operated manually with the respective buttons of the Tomcat Manager in the webapp

Answer (score 0):

You can start, stop and reload applications using [Tomcat Manager's text interface](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Start_an_Existing_Application). E.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/start?path=/webapp
```

will start the application `/webapp`. You can use it from a script through any command capable of issuing a HTTP request, e.g.:

```
curl -u user:password http://localhost:8080/manager/text/start?path=/webapp
```

where `user` and `password` are the credential of a Tomcat user with the `manager-script` role.

Comment: Ah, thank you for shedding light with your knowledge, I am very grateful that I now have a promising path to solve my dilemma. I had no clue how to approach this task. I will surely explore this idea. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Java Webapplications are defined to be executed by a JEE container. This container can be Apache Tomcat, Apache Geronimo, Wildfly or many others. There is no way around that bit.

However you can start such containers preconfigured with your webapplication through a Windows batch file. On the other hand what you describe is that the batch file is not your end - you want to be able to schedule start/stop and automatically restart if needed.

Windows comes with a great tool to startup and manage background processes. The background processes are called Service, and the JEE containers can be installed as services. Have a look at this nice documentation:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

Comment: Thank you for this alternative solution for this kind of problems.
The Tomcat9 //RS//ServiceName command requires that there is an already defined Windows service related to the webapp. IDK how is a webapp defined as a service.
The command line solution with cURL allows parameters to be passed to the execution of the webapp and seems preferable in our case. Or maybe I am wrong and that could be achieved also with the service, e.g. thru environment variables or data in files

Comment: Note you do not install a webapp as a service. It is the whole Tomcat. However if you use Tomcat for one webapp only, the name of the webapp would still make sense. Just check the section about installing the service: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Installing_services

Comment: Aha, I see. So each one of the ServiceNames are the webapps,  just like you see them in the Tomcat Manager's list of applications. Fine, this is very useful for me too, thank you